# Eloquent change value of a column with a condition

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

```
$leave = LeaveRequest::select(['id','employee_name','employee_id','from_date','to_date', 'leave_type', 'department', 'notes', 'status', 'created_at'])->get();
```

And the value of the `status` column is either 0 or 1. Can I do something like if the value is 0 .it will display `Pending` and if the value is 1 it will display `Approved`

How can I do that in my current Eloquent query? I'm using mysql as my database.

Comment: case when status = 0 then 'Pending' else 'Approved' end . Replace that with the column selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the Accessors. Define:

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value) {
    return ($value) ? "Approved" : "Pending";
}
```

in your LeaveRequest model: this will change the value of the status field. Check the docs for further information

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Thanks. This would help me a lot :)